# Cant get this trigger to work [SQL Oracle]

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alerta_Trig
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Valor ON Medicao
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.VALOR > 40)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SENSOR
        SET ALERTA = 'Alerta laranja'
        WHERE SENSOR_ID=(SELECT SENSOR_SENSOR_ID FROM MEDICAO);
    END;
```

I have this table of Sensors that are supposed to receive a String with an alert if 1 value > 40 enters the Medicao table. Any thoughs?

Comment: What error or wrong behaviour do you get?

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't said quite what is wrong I'm speculating a bit, but I can see two immediate potential problems.

You shouldn't query the same table again, generally, as you'll risk get a mutating table error. You also have no condition in the subquery so you'd be likely to get multiple rows back, and a subquery-returns-more-than-one-row error.

Presumably you're doing that subquery to try to get the ID value from the affected row, so use the :NEW pseudo-row for that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alerta_Trig
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Valor ON Medicao
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.VALOR > 40)
BEGIN
    UPDATE SENSOR
    SET ALERTA = 'Alerta laranja'
    WHERE SENSOR_ID = :NEW.SENSOR_SENSOR_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was having problems with :NEW.SENSOR_SENSOR_ID. I really appreciate it!